# Executing a stored procedure inside another stored procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am working with a bank database with two tables i.e `[Card]` and `[Transaction]`.

I have created a stored procedure `login` that gets as inputs `pin` and `cardNumber` and returns the validity of card in an output parameter. Now, I have created another stored procedure `withdraw` that gets inputs `pin`, `cardNum`, `transactionAmount` and starts a transaction. I am trying to use p1 procedure to handle the validity part. Here are the 2 procedures

```
create procedure login
    @status int output, 
    @pin varchar(4), 
    @cnum varchar(20) 
as
begin
    if  exists (select * from [Card] where PIN = @pin AND cardNum = @cnum)
    begin
        set @status = 1
    end
    else
    begin 
        set @status = 0
    end
end

alter procedure WithDraw
    @pin varchar(4), 
    @cnum varchar(20), 
    @trAmount int
as
begin
    declare @m int

    exec login @pin = N'0234', @cnum = N'2324325423336', @status = @m OUTPUT

    if (select @m) = 1
    --if exists (select * from [Card] where cardNum = @cnum AND pin = @pin)
    --working fine with above statement
    begin
        if exists (select * from [Card] 
                   where cardNum = @cnum AND pin = @pin AND (balance > @trAmount))
        begin
            update [Card] 
            set balance = balance - @trAmount 
            where cardNum = @cnum AND pin = @pin

            declare @maxID int
            select @maxID = MAX(transId) from [Transaction]

            insert into [Transaction] 
            values (@maxID + 1, GETDATE(), @cnum, @trAmount, 1)

            print 'Transaction successful'
        end
        else
        begin
            select @maxID = MAX(transId) from [Transaction]

            insert into [Transaction] 
            values(@maxID + 1, GETDATE(), @cnum, @trAmount, 4)

            print 'Transaction unsuccessful! Insufficient balance in card'
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        print 'login failed'
    end
end

exec WithDraw @pin = N'1770', @cnum = N'1324327436569', @trAmount = 50000
```

However, when I execute `withdraw` with login procedure inside, login always fails. When i execute without login procedure everything works fine. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ***PLEASE*** don't do this: `select @maxID = MAX(transId) from [Transaction]` and the use `@maxID + 1` as the new value - this **IS GUARANTEED TO FAIL** in a busy system, causing duplicate values !! Do NOT do this "by hand" yourself - use the database-provided means of `INT IDENTITY` columns and let the database handle the nitty-gritty details of dishing out unique ID values!

Comment: But how can max(transId)+1 yield a duplicate value? Anyways my requirement was to manually calculate the next id rather than using altering the table and adding identity constraint

Comment: imagine you have multiple users at the same time - let's say 2, A and B. Both want to add a new item and start this procedure. Both users will read the current value, e.g. 47 - and both will indepedently increase by one - so both get 48 - and now both try to save the new item with ID = 48 ======> BAM!!! You have your duplicate and your ID collision. ¨

Comment: @umar, run `SELECT MAX(transId) from [Transaction]` from 2 different query windows and you will get the same value. If you must increment the value manually, set the transaction isolation level to `SERIALIZABLE` and encapsulate the proc code in a transaction.